# Linux : setting locale at runtime and interprocess dependencies

Tags: c, linux, utf-8, embedded-linux

I am stuck in a strange problem.

I have two scripts (C program executables) running on ARM linux machine that are mounting the same USB device (containing chinese character filenames) on two different paths, as soon as the device is inserted.

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
                 const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
                 const void *data);
```

In the last parameter,
Script A passes "utf8" and Script B passes 0.

So, as soon as I insert the USB device, the scripts race to mount the device.

If Script A mounts first (which passes utf8 parameter), I get proper filenames. This is the `mount` command output [Notice that even second mount has utf8 as parameter, even if its not passed. Why?]

```
/dev/sdb1 on /home/root/script1 type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-r
o)
/dev/sdb1 on /home/root/script2 type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed
,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

But if script B mounts first(which passes 0 as last parameter to mount), I get broken filenames `?????.mp3` from `readdir()`. This is the `mount` command output.

```
/dev/sdb1 on /home/root/script2 type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1 on /home/root/script1 type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed
,errors=remount-ro)
```

**EDIT**

This is the basic mount code of both the scripts developed for testing(only difference in last mount argument). Both scripts are executed immediately on reboot using a service.

```
//mount the device
        ret = mount("/dev/sda1", "/home/root/script1/", "vfat", 1, "utf8");
        if (ret == 0) {
                fprintf(stdout,"mount() succeeded.\n");
                sleep(2000);
        } else {
                ret = mount("/dev/sdb1", "/home/root/script1/", "vfat", 1, "utf8");
                if(ret == 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stdout,"mount() succeeded\n");
                    sleep(2000);
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stdout,"/dev/sdb1 mount() failed: %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                    ret = mount("/dev/sdc1", "/home/root/script1/", "vfat", 1, "utf8");
                    if(ret == 0)
                    {
                        fprintf(stdout,"mount() succeeded\n");
                        sleep(2000);
                    }
                    else
                        fprintf(stdout,"mount() failed: %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                }
        }
```

Comment: Pure C, if it matters. Edited the question.

Comment: So the problem is with race condition between Script A and Script B. How it is related withc locales and C?

Comment: We cant tell you why script 2 fails as long as we dont see the mount command there. Please post the code of script2

Comment: @myaut : According to me, since the scripts are mounting the device on different paths, locale set by one script for one path, should not affect the other script locale in some other path. So I may set two different locales/encodings on two different paths and read from these different paths in different encodings. Please correct if I am wrong at this very basic point.

Comment: @InsaneCoder: your problem is mounting same filesystem twice, which is bad on its own. See my answer through. P.S. (how about more descriptive title like "Mount points wasn't applied when I mount my filesytem second time")?

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you should **never** mount same filesystem twice -- if OS drivers will decide to write twice to the same block, you'll get filesystem corruption. Use bind-mounts in such cases.

Linux, however, is smart enough to help you with that -- it will reuse older filesystem mount `super_block` (with all mountpoint flags) for a to a location.

I couldn't find it in documentation, but it is traceable through kernel source in [`sget()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/super.c#L437) which is called by `mount_bdev()`:

```
hlist_for_each_entry(old, &type->fs_supers, s_instances) {
        if (!test(old, data))
                continue;
        if (!grab_super(old))
                goto retry;
        if (s) {
                up_write(&s->s_umount);
                destroy_super(s);
                s = NULL;
        }
        return old;
}
```

In this snippet it'll seek for previous instance of `super_block` corresponding to a block device, and if it already exists -- simply returns it.

---

Some practical proof using SystemTap:

```
# stap -e 'probe kernel.function("sget").return {
        sb = $return;
        active = @cast(sb, "super_block")->s_active->counter;
        fsi = @cast(sb, "super_block")->s_fs_info;
        uid = fsi == 0 ? -1
            : @cast(fsi, "msdos_sb_info", "vfat")->options->fs_uid;
        printf("%p active=%d uid=%d\n", sb, active, uid);
    }'
```

Setting uid in second mount doesn't alter option, but increases number of active mounts (obvious):

```
  # mount /dev/sdd1 /tmp/mnt1
  0xffff8803ce87e800 active=1 uid=-1
  # mount -o uid=1000 /dev/sdd1 /tmp/mnt2
  0xffff8803ce87e800 active=2 uid=0
```

Mounting in reverse order also inherits mount options:

```
  # mount -o uid=1000 /dev/sdd1 /tmp/mnt2
  0xffff8803cc609c00 active=1 uid=-1
  # mount /dev/sdd1 /tmp/mnt1
  0xffff8803cc609c00 active=2 uid=1000
```

---

If you wish to know who was responsible for such behavior, ask Linus, similiar code exists since 0.11:

```
struct super_block * get_super(int dev)
{
    struct super_block * s;

    if (!dev)
        return NULL;
    s = 0+super_block;
    while (s < NR_SUPER+super_block)
        if (s->s_dev == dev) {
            wait_on_super(s);
            if (s->s_dev == dev)
                return s;
            s = 0+super_block;
        } else
            s++;
    return NULL;
}
```

(but when this code was in charge, `sys_mount()` explicitly checked that no other mountpoints exist for that superblock).

You can possibly try to ask a question at LKML.